# How do I kill a http server from another function

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)


func handlerfunc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello World" )
    }

    http.ServeContent(w, r, str , time.Now(), f)
}

func PleaseStart(){
    http.HandleFunc("/" , handlerfunc )
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil))
}

func kill_server() {
    //How do I kill server from here
}


func main() {
    go PleaseStart()

    kill_server()
}
```

I start a http.server that responds with hello world, how do I kill it from kill_server function
Is this possible without rewritting everything?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39320025/go-how-to-stop-http-listenandserve/42533360#42533360

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not. `http.ListenAndServe` generates a local `http.Server` instance, which you cannot gain access to, which is what you would need to be able to stop it. You'll need to create your own `http.Server` instance, and register your handlers with that instead of using `http.HandleFunc`. Then you can shut down the server using `Close()` to shut down immediately, or `Shutdown()` to do a graceful stop (letting requests in flight complete before shutting down).

```
var server *http.Server
//...
func PleaseStart() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handlerfunc)
    server = &http.Server{
        Addr:    ":80",
        Handler: http.DefaultServeMux,
    }
    log.Fatal(server.ListenAndServe())
}

func kill_server() {
    server.Close()
}
```

Comment: How do I create my own http.Server instance, like a package level variable? @Adrian

Comment: Added a code example displaying immediate shutdown. For graceful shutdown, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39320025/go-how-to-stop-http-listenandserve/42533360#42533360 or https://gist.github.com/peterhellberg/38117e546c217960747aacf689af3dc2

Comment: Note also that the given code is the minimum change to do what you're asking; I would advise against using the default mux or default server (or any package-level variables in the stdlib like flags or log) for anything but a throwaway project.

Comment: Why does shutdown and close kill the my whole program? @Adrian

Comment: Because your main() returns after kill_server(). When main returns, the program exits.