# How to add an after callback in Gin framework

Tags: go, go-gin

I need to quit the application with `os.Exit(0)` AFTER HTTP request has finished completely. My application asks another server if it needs an upgrade, so I need to quit for performing a self upgrade with a reboot, but I don't want to break current HTTP request.

When I try to quit in middleware after `c.Next()` or at the end of handler function, the browser gives error: `localhost didn’t send any data`.

How this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, your program is terminating before the HTTP connection completes cleanly - you need to wait for the HTTP transaction to finish and then exit. Fortunately since Go 1.8 `http.Server` has a [`Shutdown` method](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Server.Shutdown) that does what you need.

> Shutdown gracefully shuts down the server without interrupting any active connections. Shutdown works by first closing all open listeners, then closing all idle connections, and then waiting indefinitely for connections to return to idle and then shut down.

So, the general approach would be:

```
exitChan := make(chan struct{})

// Get a reference to exitChan to your handlers somehow

h := &http.Server{
    // your config
}
go func(){
    h.ListenAndServe() // Run server in goroutine so as not to block
}()

<-exitChan // Block on channel
h.Shutdown(nil) // Shutdown cleanly with a timeout of 5 seconds
```

And then `exitChan <- struct{}{}` in your handler/middleware when shutdown is required.

See also: [How to stop http.ListenAndServe()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39320025/how-to-stop-http-listenandserve)

Comment: Yes, it works. But some extra lines are required to make it work with Gin.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this example on their github repository: 
[graceful-shutdown](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/master/examples/graceful-shutdown/graceful-shutdown/server.go)

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "time"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
    router := gin.Default()
    router.GET("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
        c.String(http.StatusOK, "Welcome Gin Server")
    })

    srv := &http.Server{
        Addr:    ":8080",
        Handler: router,
    }

    go func() {
        // service connections
        if err := srv.ListenAndServe(); err != nil && err != http.ErrServerClosed {
            log.Fatalf("listen: %s\n", err)
        }
    }()

    // Wait for interrupt signal to gracefully shutdown the server with
    // a timeout of 5 seconds.
    quit := make(chan os.Signal)
    signal.Notify(quit, os.Interrupt)
    <-quit
    log.Println("Shutdown Server ...")

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5*time.Second)
    defer cancel()
    if err := srv.Shutdown(ctx); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Server Shutdown:", err)
    }
    log.Println("Server exiting")
}
```

Comment: Consider as well providing an explanation of the code to increase long-term value of your answer.