# stop server without exiting program golang

Tags: http, go

I am using golang to run a simple server on http://localhost:8080. I need a way to stop the server and restart a different server when a user accesses http://localhost:8080/winrestart. So far I have this:

```
package main


import (
  "net/http" //serving files and stuff
  "log"      //logging that the server is running and other stuff
  "fmt"      //"congrats on winning!"
)


func main() {

  //servemux
  srvmx := http.NewServeMux()

  //handlers that serve the home html file when called
  fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./home/"))
  os := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./lvlone/"))
  ws := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./win/"))

  //creates custom server
  server := http.Server {
    Addr: ":8080",
    Handler: srvmx,
  }

  //handles paths by serving correct files
  srvmx.Handle("/", fs)
  srvmx.Handle("/lvlione/", http.StripPrefix("/lvlione/", os))
  srvmx.Handle("/win/", http.StripPrefix("/win/", ws))
  srvmx.HandleFunc("/winrestart/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    fmt.Println("server is being closed")

    //creates new servemux
    wsm := http.NewServeMux()

    //this handler just redirects people to the beggining
    rh := http.RedirectHandler("http://127.0.0.1:8080/", 308)

    //create new redirect server
    redirector := http.Server {
      Addr: ":8080",
      Handler: wsm,
    }

    //Handle all paths by redirecting
    wsm.Handle("/lvlione/", rh)
    wsm.Handle("/win/", rh)
    wsm.Handle("/winrestart/", rh)

    //logs redirect server is Listening
    log.Println("redirecting...")
    server.Close()
    redirector.ListenAndServe()
  })

  //logs that server is Listening
  log.Println("Listening...")
  //starts normal level server
  server.ListenAndServe()
}
```

As of now, the server closes and the program exits, but no new server is started. Is there a way this can be done?

Comment: This has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39320025/how-to-stop-http-listenandserve

Comment: There are packages for graceful restart already, such as [facebookgo/grace](https://github.com/facebookgo/grace). Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @MichaelHampton [like this?](https://2static.fjcdn.com/pictures/Reinvent+the+wheel_279779_5664999.jpg) if OP is starting with Go it may be useful to reinvent everything for their own sake.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop http.ListenAndServe()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39320025/how-to-stop-http-listenandserve)

Comment: @ShrimpPhaser I tried using the Close function but it closes the program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the main thread becomes unblocked when you call `server.Close()`

The main thread starts the server on it's very last line: `server.ListenAndServe()` but when the `/winrestart/` handler method gets called; this handler method calls `server.Close()`, which stops the server, and the original blocking call to `server.ListenAndServe()` becomes unblocked. The main goroutine exits, and the program exits.

Runnable, simplified example showing this:

https://play.golang.org/p/RM1uNASBaC1