# Golang graceful HTTP server shutdown with error handling

Tags: http, go, go-graceful

I'm in the process of getting my HTTP server to gracefully shut down. I've taken tips from the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39320025/how-to-stop-http-listenandserve), and have set up my code like this so far:

```
func start() {

    //......

    //START HTTP/SOCKET LISTENER
    if settings.TLS {
        httpServer = makeServer("/wss", settings.TLS);
    } else {
        httpServer = makeServer("/ws", settings.TLS);
    }

    //...
}

func makeServer(handleDir string, tls bool) (*http.Server) {
    server := &http.Server{Addr: settings.IP+":"+strconv.Itoa(settings.Port)}
    http.HandleFunc(handleDir, socketInitializer)
    if tls {
        go func() {
            err := server.ListenAndServeTLS(settings.CertFile, settings.PrivKeyFile)
            if err != nil {
                serverError(err)
            }
        }()
    }else{
        go func() {
            err := server.ListenAndServe()
            if err != nil {
                serverError(err)
            }
        }()
    }

    //
    return server
}
```

So, I have some questions about how this all works now:

1) The answer I linked above states "NOTE: there is a chance that next line won't have time to run..." for the `ListenAndServe()` error handling inside the goroutine. How can I make sure that `serverError()` will guarantee completion? Do I need to do some sort of blocking on that thread or do I make a channel on the main thread that it can call?

2) As of right now, I'm not sure if I have a way of telling if I've `Server.ShutDown()` the `http.Server`, or if it threw an error and shut itself down. Does the `ListenAndServe()` error get thrown even if I used the `Server.ShutDown()` method? Is that why the accepted answer in the link uses `err != http.ErrServerClosed` when checking the `ListenAndServe()` error?

3) The `start()` function is (of course) ran on the main thread. Don't I need to block that thread somehow so the program doesn't return and exit, or does `ListenAndServe()` take care of that for me?

4) After I call `Server.ShutDown()` do I need to do anything to shut down the `http.HandleFunc()` listeners?

Any amount of help on any of these topics would be greatly appreciated, so don't worry if you can't touch on everything at once :)

EDIT: If anyone wants to see how I ended up getting this all to work right, you can look at [this file](https://github.com/hewiefreeman/GopherGameServer/blob/master/server.go), line 225 and on.

Comment: More examles of  graceful shutdown here
https://gist.github.com/peterhellberg/38117e546c217960747aacf689af3dc2

Comment: I took a look at that, but still had all these unanswered questions about what exactly was going on. I've got it all working perfectly now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`main` function should somehow wait for all go routines which you want completely done.

So, the 1) question: you should block on the main routine to make sure `serverError` can be executed.

And the 3) question: absolutely you should block on `start()` or outside `start()` by yourself, or the program will exit immediately.

As for 2). the doc points out:

> ListenAndServe always returns a non-nil error.

so `err != http.ErrServerClosed` just works for situation `Server.ShutDown()`. Yet there's other errors may occur.

4) Nothing to do to shut down the `http.HandleFunc()` because `Server.ShutDown()` will wait for requests which is processing done.