# Problem with running multiple servers in error group

Tags: multithreading, go, concurrency

I have a struct:

```
type MultiServer struct {
    servers []*http.Server
}

func New(servers ...*http.Server) *MultiServer {
    return &MultiServer{servers: servers}
}

func (m *MultiServer) ListenAndServe() error {
    var g errgroup.Group
    for _, s := range m.servers {
        s := s
        g.Go(s.ListenAndServe)
    }

    return g.Wait()
}
```

I expect that `ListenAndServe` returns immediately if one of the servers return error.
So I pass incorrect port to one of the servers:

```
func TestListenAndServe(t *testing.T) {
    one := makeServer(":8080")
    two := makeServer("::8080") // that is incorrect port
    ms := New(one, two)
    done := make(chan error)
    go func() {
        done <- ms.ListenAndServe()
    }()
    select {
    case err := <-done:
        if err == nil {
            t.Fatal("error expected")
        }
    case <-makeTimeChan(5 * time.Second):
        t.Fatal("timeout")
    }
}

func makeServer(port string) *http.Server {
    serveMux := http.NewServeMux()
    hello := func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "hello\n")
    }
    serveMux.HandleFunc("/hello", hello)
    return &http.Server{
        Addr:         port,
        Handler:      serveMux,
        ReadTimeout:  10 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout: 10 * time.Second,
    }

}

func makeTimeChan(d time.Duration) <-chan time.Time {
    t := time.NewTimer(d)
    return t.C

}
```

And I get "timeout" constantly if my MultiServer has more than one server. I assume that it is something related to running servers in a loop because if I replace `ListenAndServe` with:

```
func (m *MultiServer) ListenAndServe() error {
    var g errgroup.Group
    for _, s := range m.servers {
        _= s
        g.Go(func(){ return errors.New("")})
    }

    return g.Wait()
}
```

everything works as expected.
Could anybody help me sort out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Aside: makeTimeChan can be replaced with [time.After](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#After).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using `http.ListenAndServe` and `golang.org/x/sync/errgroup`:

- An errgroup's `Wait` returns when *all functions* have returned.
- The errgroup's `Go` call calls the given function, and if the function returns an error, calls the cancel function in the context of the group.  If you have not called `WithContext` to create a group that has a context, though, you have a group that has no context, so no cancel() happens.

Your `eg.Wait()` call waits for both `ListenAndServe` calls to return.  If you had a cancellation function and used that to stop *other* `ListenAndServe` invocations, that would help.  See [How to stop http.ListenAndServe()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39320025/1256452).  But you'll also need a `WithContext` so that you have a way to know *when* to stop the other `ListenAndServe` calls.  Note that you will want to stop all others, not just the (singular) other, once you have more than two such.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is a shame thad I didn't know it before. I was certain that it is difference between WaitGroup and ErrorGroup that ErrorGroup terminates after first error. I was so certain that I have not even checked the doc. Now I see it.