# Start Go HTTP server, do something, then shut it down once task is done

Tags: go

I'm setting up an OAuth2 flow from a CLI application, I'm working on. I need to create a temporary HTTP server for the provider to send the callback to, e.g. `localhost:8080/callback`

Once the provider has sent the details I need, I want to be able to shut the HTTP server down, just to keep everything clean. I think what I'm looking for is Routines and Wait Groups, but I'm still quite new to this area.

This is what I have so far. I have redacted the part that sends the user to the provider, as my main issue is simply how to shut down the HTTP server once the `token` variable has been captured.

1. Server starts
2. User is directed to authorization URL at the provider site
3. User approves the request
4. Provider directs user back to `localhost:8080/callback`
5. URL includes client-side only params so I have to server HTML to use JS to capture the values and send it back to the server
6. Server receives token and can then shutdown

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    // Start local HTTP serevr to listen for response
    serverDone := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    serverDone.Add(1)
    Start(serverDone)

    // ... Process to start OAuth2 flow
    // User is directed to provider website
    // User approves
    // Provider direct user back to localhost/callback
    
    serverDone.Wait()
}

func Start(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {

    srv := &http.Server{Addr: ":8080"}
    http.HandleFunc("/callback", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        token := r.URL.Query().Get("token")
        if token != "" {
            fmt.Println("Found Token:", token)
            // Shut down server here
        } else {
            // Server HTML page to fetch token and return to server at /callback
        }
    })

    go func() {
        // let main know we are done cleaning up
        defer wg.Done()

        // ErrServerClosed on graceful close
        if err := srv.ListenAndServe(); err != http.ErrServerClosed {
            log.Fatalf("ListenAndServe(): %v", err)
        }
    }()
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop http.ListenAndServe()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39320025/how-to-stop-http-listenandserve)

Comment: @PrathikRajendranM This is what I followed, however the server shuts down before the action of grabbing the token can be completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
var ctxShutdown, cancel = context.WithCancel(context.Background())
```

Then:

```
cancel() // to say sorry, above.
// graceful-shutdown
err := srv.Shutdown(context.Background())
```

Try this:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    serverDone := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    serverDone.Add(1)
    Start(serverDone)
    serverDone.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Done that.")
}

var ctxShutdown, cancel = context.WithCancel(context.Background())

func Start(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    srv := &http.Server{Addr: ":8080"}
    http.HandleFunc("/callback", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        select {
        case <-ctxShutdown.Done():
            fmt.Println("Sorry: Shuting down ...")
            return
        default:
        }
        token := r.URL.Query().Get("token")
        if token != "" {
            fmt.Println("Found Token:", token)
            fmt.Println("Shuting down ...")
            // Shut down server here
            cancel() // to say sorry, above.
            // graceful-shutdown
            err := srv.Shutdown(context.Background())
            if err != nil {
                log.Println("server.Shutdown:", err)
            }

        } else {
            fmt.Fprintln(w, "Hi") // Server HTML page to fetch token and return to server at /callback
        }
    })

    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        if err := srv.ListenAndServe(); err != http.ErrServerClosed {
            log.Fatalf("ListenAndServe(): %v", err)
        }
        fmt.Println("Bye.")
    }()
}
```

Run and open http://127.0.0.1:8080/callback?token=2

Output:

```
Found Token: 2
Shuting down ...
Bye.
Done that.
```