# Golang: TLS Webserver not starting in a waitgroup (there for graceful shutdown)

Tags: go

I´m using a https-Server in golang to serve some functions and files secured with basic auth. This all had worked wonderfully to the point I implemented a waitgroup for shutting down the server. This is needed cause i´m programming on gokrazy and have to shutdown the server one time a day at 0 o´clock to renew the certificate with let´s encrypt.

I have tried to implemet as in the following thread discribed, but it´s not working anymore ([How to stop http.ListenAndServe()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39320025/how-to-stop-http-listenandserve)).

The HTTP-Server ist starting and working fine, the HTTPS-Server isn´t starting.

Hope you can help me with this problem
Yours
Christian

**Code:**

**Main Thread** (starting both web servers (HTTP and HTTPS fpr 30 secounds):

```
//Start Web Server in Background
    log.Printf("Starting Web Server Process")
    httpServerExitDone := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    httpServerExitDone.Add(1)
    srvHTTP := startHttpServer(httpServerExitDone)
    httpsServerExitDone := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    httpsServerExitDone.Add(1)
    srvHTTPS := startHttpsServer(httpsServerExitDone)
    log.Printf("Webserver process started successfully")

    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)

    if err := srvHTTP.Shutdown(context.TODO()); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error stopping the server: %s", err)
    }
    if err := srvHTTPS.Shutdown(context.TODO()); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error stopping the server: %s", err)
    }
    httpServerExitDone.Wait()
    httpsServerExitDone.Wait()
```

**HTTP-Server**

```
//WEB-Server
func startHttpServer(wg *sync.WaitGroup) *http.Server {
    srvHTTP := &http.Server{
        Addr: ":" + config.PortHTTP,
        Handler: http.HandlerFunc(redirect),
    }

    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        log.Printf("Starting HTTP Redictor Server on Port %s", config.PortHTTP)

        // always returns error. ErrServerClosed on graceful close
        if err := srvHTTP.ListenAndServe(); err != http.ErrServerClosed {
            log.Fatalf("Error with HTTP-Server: %s", err)
        }
        
    }()

    // returning reference so caller can call Shutdown()
    return srvHTTP
}
```

**HTTPS-Server (not working)**

```
//WEB-Server
func startHttpsServer(wg *sync.WaitGroup) *http.Server {
    srvHTTPS := &http.Server{
        Addr: ":" + config.PortHTTPS,
    }

    //BasicAuth
    authentificator := auth.NewBasicAuthenticator("Dlock", secretForWebUser)

    //Static sites
    devFS := flag.Bool("devFS", false, "use local file system")
    flag.Parse()
    fs := http.FileServer(assets)
    if *devFS {
        fmt.Printf("Use local dev file sytem\n")
        fs = http.FileServer(http.Dir("../web/files"))
    }
    http.HandleFunc("/", authentificator.Wrap(func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *auth.AuthenticatedRequest) {
        fs.ServeHTTP(w, &req.Request)
    }))

    //Main-API
    http.HandleFunc("/dlock/v1/management/add", authentificator.Wrap(func (w http.ResponseWriter, r *auth.AuthenticatedRequest) {
        newHttpRequest("/dlock/v1/management/add", &r.Request, &w)
    }))
    http.HandleFunc("/dlock/v1/management/get", authentificator.Wrap(func (w http.ResponseWriter, r *auth.AuthenticatedRequest) {
        newHttpRequest("/dlock/v1/management/get", &r.Request, &w)
    }))
    http.HandleFunc("/dlock/v1/websv", authentificator.Wrap(func (w http.ResponseWriter, r *auth.AuthenticatedRequest) {
        newHttpRequest("/dlock/v1/websv", &r.Request, &w)
    }))

    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        log.Printf("Starting HTTPS Server on Port %s", config.PortHTTPS)

        // always returns error. ErrServerClosed on graceful close
        if err := srvHTTPS.ListenAndServeTLS(config.Crt, config.Key); err != http.ErrServerClosed {
            log.Fatalf("Error with HTTP-Server: %s", err)
        }       
    }()

    // returning reference so caller can call Shutdown()
    return srvHTTPS
}
```

**Log** if i start the server locally and connect to the HTTP-Server:

```
2021/10/16 16:12:11 Starting Web Server Process
2021/10/16 16:12:11 Webserver process started successfully
2021/10/16 16:12:11 Starting HTTPS Server on Port 8443
2021/10/16 16:12:11 Starting HTTP Redictor Server on Port 8080
2021/10/16 16:12:14 redirect to: https://localhost:8443/
```

**Error** if i coonect to the HTTPS-Site:

Timeout

Answer (score 0):

it turned out, that only my Firefox has a problem with the site and the port.

If I change the port it works - if i try it with chrome it works.