cpprest http client send request before server is up
I have a server program written in Golang that listens on 127.0.0.1:5555, and another program in C++ that uses cpprest to create a client and send a POST request to 127.0.0.1:5555 upon execution.
When I start the server program first and then execute the C++ program, everything works well. However, if I run the C++ program first, it sends a request, and then after a few seconds, try to execute the server program, I encounter an error:
"listen tcp 127.0.0.1:5555: bind: address already in use."
How can I resolve this issue?
this is the c++ code code:
void HttpClientPubSubConnection<Ttopic, Tdata>::publish(const Ttopic& topic, const Tdata& data) const {
    web::http::client::http_client_config config;
    config.set_timeout(std::chrono::seconds(30));

    web::http::client::http_client client(U("http://127.0.0.1:5555"), config);

    web::json::value body;
    body[U("data")] = web::json::value::string(data);

    try {
        client.request(web::http::methods::POST, U(topic), body)
        .then([topic, data](web::http::http_response response) {
            if (response.status_code() != web::http::status_codes::OK) {
            throw std::runtime_error(
                "Failed to publish message. Topic: " + topic + 
                ", Data: " + data + 
                ", Status Code: " + std::to_string(response.status_code()));
            }
        })
        .wait();
    } catch (const web::http::http_exception& ex) {
        // Specific handling for timeout errors
        auto error_message = std::string(ex.what());
        if (error_message.find("Failed to read HTTP status line") != std::string::npos) {
            throw std::runtime_error(
                "Timeout occurred while waiting for the server to respond. Topic: " + topic + ", Data: " + data);
        } else {
            throw std::runtime_error("HTTP error: " + error_message);
        }
    } catch (const std::exception& ex) {
        // General error handling
        throw std::runtime_error("An unexpected error occurred: " + std::string(ex.what()));
    }
}

this is the go server code:
type HTTPServer struct {
    Address        string
    HealthRoute    string
}

func (s *HTTPServer) Init(address, healthRoute string) error {
    if address == "" {
        return fmt.Errorf("invalid input: serverAddress must be non-empty")
    }
    s.Address = address  // 127.0.0.1:5555
    s.HealthRoute = healthRoute

    return nil
}

func (s HTTPServer) Start() {
    // Health check route
    http.HandleFunc(s.HealthRoute, func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        log.Print("successful health check")
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    })

    log.Printf("Starting server on %s\n", s.Address)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(s.Address, nil))
}

I am attempting to implement a mechanism where if I do not receive a response from the server, the client will retry. In this scenario, the server might become available after the second request, and the third request would successfully go through. However, keep in mind that the server cannot become available after the first request.

Surely that error is caused by the Go code creating the socket? Can you show the code for that?

added to the question above

What are the results of netstat or a similar service to see what service is running on the port?

once i execute the cpp program that send request (and the go program didn't execute yet) and I execute the command:
ss -tuln | grep 5555
I got:
tcp   LISTEN 0      511        127.0.0.1:5555       0.0.0.0:*

You would have this problem with curl or wget as well. There is nothing C++-specific about your problem.

So that means the port is in use then. The likeliest is that the Go server didnt release that port. You want to search for "Graceful Shutdown". That should relieve the issue. You can also check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75117142/how-to-close-http-port-in-go

@Botje
once i execute curl before i execute the server app I got:
curl  -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "" http://127.0.0.1:5555/health
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 5555 after 0 ms: Connection refused
but after that once I execute the server app it's successfully started to listen to 127.0.0.1:5555 unlike after I send request by the cpp program that uses cpprest client

@theNoble247
but the problem isn't that the server didn't release the port because the server didn't run beofre, it's the first time it execute. the only thing that execute before is the cpp program that send request by cpprest client (while the server didn't started because this is the case i want to check)

You are aware that Windows tends not to free up listen sockets immediately after the process exits, yes? I'm fairly certain that is what you are seeing.

i'm tring to create mechanizm that the cpp program send requests for route /helath to the server till it will get response, because there is option that the server will start a few seconds after the cpp program. but after the first attempt of the cpp program it's destroy the port so the server cannot up

That would be an amazing denial of service vector. Please verify what is happening with procmon.

@user16284772 You tested when running the server, and it was ok. You then shut down the server and the client. You then run the client before running the server, and when you start the server you get an issue, is that correct?
if that is correct, it means from the previous run, the shutdown may not have been graceful and the port binding was not released.

@Botje
i'm working on Linux

@theNoble247
that correct but i also tested that I configure to use another port for example 5666 and before I execute the server, I execute the cpp program that runs and send request and only after that tried to execute the server but I got the same error like I describe above. this is why I think the server is not the issue here

In that case, please strace the client with -e trace=%net and look for bind calls. It makes no sense that cpprestsdk would bind to the server port. A simple socket + connect should suffice.

Im with @Botje on this one. It doesnt make sense that the cpprestclient would bind to the port (unless theres something i dont know). I guess check port bindings before and after the client run to trace the exact process thats binding to the port. Over and above that, i dont think we can assist much

Also, ss -tulnp should tell you which process is using the socket.

Note that cpprest has been deprecated and unmaintained for a few years now, I'd recommend not using it for new projects
